# Access SAP Cloud Platform: OData provisioning using Basic Authentication

Tags: odata, provisioning, sap-cloud-platform

I have followed the https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/08/consume-sap-gateway-odata-service-in-sap-cloud-platform-workflow/ blog and implemented. But when I am trying to access the OData provisioning from postman getting the error "Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed." Any idea what could be the step which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is no step in the blog.
Your browser just blocks javascript execution. It may blocked by your company ( pc administrator )

Depending on your browser check out the following links:

Chrome:  http://www.activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/chrome

Firefox:
http://www.activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/firefox

Internet Explorer: 
http://www.activatejavascript.org/en/instructions/ie

If you use a complete diffrent browser please check if there is any option how to turn on JavaScript. Many browsers are chromnium based, that means they are very similar to chrome ( also in the settings, so it might be worth to check this ).

If your browser does not support JavaScript, you need to change it unfortunately.